# Set field's value during migration, based on another table value

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-migration

I have 3 models in my Django project:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class C(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

So the relations are A->B one-to-many, B->C one-to-many.
What I want to do is add field `a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` to model `C`, and during migration I want to set values of `c` equal `b.a__id` value. So I achieve new relation A->C one-to-many. How can i do this?

I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: you can do that by changing x and y

Comment: @e4c5 May you provide more details?